# error executing ImageMagick command 'convert' - xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to add dev tape and version number in my app following this [tutorial](https://www.kodeco.com/1716-how-to-change-your-app-icon-at-build-time), but I'm getting error

> "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

This error occurs when I execute the command `convert betaRibbon.png -resize 120x120 resizedBetaRibbon.png` in the **Build Phases/Icon Change Script**, however when executing the same command through the terminal I do not get any error, understanding that I have the imagemagick and ghostscript are installed correctly. Also I can't execute script files from xcode either. Any ideas?.

I share script code

```
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin
IFS=$'\n'

function generateIcon () {
  BASE_IMAGE_NAME=$1
    
  TARGET_PATH="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/${BASE_IMAGE_NAME}"
  BASE_IMAGE_PATH=$(find ${SRCROOT} -name ${BASE_IMAGE_NAME})
    
  WIDTH=$(identify -format %w ${BASE_IMAGE_PATH})
    
  /opt/homebrew/bin/convert betaRibbon.png -resize $WIDTHx$WIDTH resizedRibbon.png
  /opt/homebrew/bin/convert ${BASE_IMAGE_PATH} -fill white -font Times-Bold -pointsize 18 -gravity south -annotate 0 "Hello World" - | /opt/homebrew/bin/composite resizedRibbon.png - ${TARGET_PATH}
}

generateIcon "60.png"
generateIcon "120.png"
```

Comment: Try adding the full path to the `convert` command line: `/some/path/convert betaRibbon.png...`. If you don't know the path, enter `which convert` in a terminal window.

Comment: @HangarRash. Update with share command but my images are not updating

Comment: What are the return codes? What are the actual commands, once all substitutions have been performed? Did you try to replace your pipe by two commands and a temporary file (or insert a `tee somefile` stage) so that you can check what goes on there?

Comment: There are several errors in your script, try pasting it into https://shellcheck.net and update your question when sorted out.

Comment: Take out the long `/opt/homebrew/bin/convert` stuff and simply set your PATH properly at the start.

Comment: The compound, piped command seems unnecessarily complicated. If you explain what you are trying to do, with representative input and output images, there's probably a much simpler, single command.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am following the indicated tutorial, but I am interested in knowing how to add my ROUTE correctly. Some example?. @MarkSetchell